# How can I input an integer in a textbox and get a specific IF or ELSE-IF result?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to input a numerical value in a text box ranging from 0 to 100, then press a button and display the corresponding grade. So far, I have this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnIF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] i = new int[1];
        txtNumK.Text = i[0].ToString();
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter test " + i);
            bool result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i[0]);
            if (!result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This program only accept numbers.");
            }

            if (i[0] >= 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is A");
            }
            if (i[0] >= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is B");
            }
            if (i[0] >= 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is C");
            }
            if (i[0] >= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is D");
            }
            if (i[0] >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is F");
            }
            else if (i[0] > 0 || i[0] < 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, the number MUST be between 0 and 100");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your result is:" + i[0]);
        } 
    }

    private void txtNumK_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Every time I input a number in the text box, the value within it is turned back into a 0.

Comment: **(1)** what is the point of `int[] i = new int[1];` instead of `int i` ? **(2)** why the PC tag? **(3)** Your `if` blocks need to be chained (`if { ... } else if { ... } else if { ... }`), otherwise you're going to enter multiple if blocks (e.g. for value `95`, you will enter every single `if` block. **(4)** `if (i[0] > 0 || i[0] < 100)` make no sense. You want the opposite: `if (i[0] < 0 || i[0] >100) ` since you need to enter the `if` when the number is **NOT** between 0 and 100

Comment: 1. I've never thought of using `int i` up until now, I guess. 2. This is what mild OCD does to you. 3. That's an interesting tidbit of information. A question rises, however; must I put the strings of codes within the bra-- Never mind, I answered that myself. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Without meaning any offense, some of these would've become apparent if you step through the code using breakpoints and look at the realtime values of your variables :)

Comment: I have not studied on breakpoints yet, so I guess that should be the cause of my apparent issue. Again, thank you. Also, no offense taken!

Comment: you do not need the opening `{` after the following 
`xtNumK.Text = i[0].ToString();
        {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your assignment backwards.  You want:

```
i[0] = Int32.parse(txtNumk.text);
```

Comment: You mean I should replace `txtNumK.Text = i[0].ToString();` with `i[0] = Int32.parse(txtNumk.text);`? Come to think of it, it may seem that I have reversed it indeed.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.